# How to keep clicks from menu from interfering with game state?

Tags: mouse

I ran into a problem coding my game in which when I click the play button on the newly implemented menu, it also creates a bullet from my player. The player and the menu both rely on the mouse input. How would I make it so that this doesn't occur? Perhaps how would I delay input from the mouse for a second until after the game starts?

Thank you.

```
public static boolean pressed = false;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    int mx = (int) e.getX();
    int my = (int) e.getY();


    if(Game.state == STATE.MENU) {
        if(Menu.playButton.contains(mx, my))
        {
            // Pressed Play Button          
            pressed = true;
            Game.setState(Game.STATE.GAME);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++)
        {
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player && pressed == true)
            {
                handler.addObject(new Bullet(tempObject.getX()+16,
                        tempObject.getY()+24, ID.Bullet, handler, mx, my, game));
                bullets_shot += 1;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the link to your github project because it will change over time, reducing the correlation between this question and what's actually pointed by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setting up a flag that indicates if the menu is open should be enough.

The player should check the flag state, and in case it's true, don't shoot.

EDIT:

I updated your function adding an else condition to the check on the game state:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    int mx = (int) e.getX();
    int my = (int) e.getY();
    pressed = true;

    if(Game.state == STATE.MENU) {
        if(Menu.playButton.contains(mx, my))
        {
            // Pressed Play Button
            Game.setState(Game.STATE.GAME);
        }
        if(Menu.helpButton.contains(mx, my))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "W: up, "
                + "S: down, D: right, A: left, "
                + "ESC: Pause ");
        }
        else if(Menu.quitButton.contains(mx,my)) 
        {   
            // Pressed Quit Button
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    else{ //<--- Added this else
        for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++)
        {
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player)
            {
                handler.addObject(new Bullet(tempObject.getX()+16,
                        tempObject.getY()+24, ID.Bullet, handler, mx, my, game));
                bullets_shot += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited it above to show how I set it up. I have the boolean variable set up but it still shoots when I press the play button.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++)
    {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player)
        {
            handler.addObject(new Bullet(tempObject.getX()+16,
                    tempObject.getY()+24, ID.Bullet, handler, mx, my, game));
            bullets_shot += 1;

        }
    }
```

You do the bullet stuff while in the `Game.state == State.MENU` state. You need some other state like `State.PLAY` And only be able to create bullets while actually in the game. Not the menus. Hope this hopes! :)